# jquery validation checks not working properly

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submit").click(function(){
                if($('.disrtrict')[0].selectedIndex<=0){
                    $("#error1").html("district field is empty");

                } 

                if($(".block")[0].selectedIndex<=0){
                    $("#error2").html("block field is empty");  
                }


                if($(".village")[0].selectedIndex<=0){
                    $("#error3").html("village field is empty");    
                }

            });
});
```

above is my jquery script.i am new to jquery and try to learn jquery. my problem is where i use return false.what the concept of return true and false and i use `if($(".block")[0].selectedIndex<=0)`  can we use `if($(".block").val()==" ")` if any one have standard checks please provide help.thank in advance.

Comment: use jquery validation lib and you have to not write that code. It is easy to use and works like a charm. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: There are validation plugins available for jquery. Consider using one of them to make your life easier.

Comment: There isn't any `return false` in your script.

Comment: error massage is not showing.in div tag

Answer (score 2):

if its a form submission the `return true` will allow form to submit the form later executing of javascript and `return false` will not submit the form after javascript

now regarding jQuery validation , yes you can use `if($(".class").val()=='')` for empty or non selection

Answer (score 1):

Inside your if condition, after the error message, you can use return false to avoid form submit..

```
if($(".block").val()=="")
```

The above code will work, if your first option value is empty.

Comment: can we write return false after $("#error1").html("");for every check

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$(".submit").click(function () {
    if ($('.disrtrict').val() === '') {
        $("#error1").html("district field is empty");
        return false;
    }
    if ($(".block").val() === '') {
        $("#error2").html("block field is empty");
        return false;
    }
    if ($(".village").val() === '') {
        $("#error3").html("village field is empty");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MJuC8/)

Comment: :-you look familiar to jquery sir please explain when and where we use return true and false.

Comment: Use `return false` when you want to prevent the click event and to prevent `form` from being submitted and use `return true` when the form has passed all the validations and you want the `form` to be submitted after that. I hope you got that!